What does Nietzsche mean by this?

"Main thought! The individual himself is a fallacy. Everything which
happens in us is in itself something else which we do not know. ‘The
individual’ is merely a sum of conscious feelings and judgments and
misconceptions, a belief, a piece of the true life system or many
pieces thought together and spun together, a ‘unity’, that doesn’t
hold together. We are buds on a single tree—what do we know about what
can become of us from the interests of the tree! But we have a
consciousness as though we would and should be everything, a phantasy
of ‘I’ and all ‘not I.’ Stop feeling oneself as this phantastic ego!
Learn gradually to discard the supposed individual! Discover the
fallacies of the ego! Recognize egoism as fallacy! The opposite is not
to be understood as altruism! This would be love of other supposed
individuals! No! Get beyond ‘myself’ and ‘yourself’! Experience
cosmically!"
-The quote is apparently unpublished but found in Nietzsche's Complete works, critical study edition Book 9, 11 [7]. Translation taken from Nietzsche and Zen : Self-overcoming without a Self by André van der Braak.

This entire paragraph seems so contradictory to Nietzsche's entire philosphical project and is reminiscent of Buddhism than any of his philosophy.

@KashifKhan Please give a precise reference to this quote, thanks.

The quote is apparently unpublished but found in Nietzsche's Complete works, critical study edition Book 9, 11 [7]. Translated in Nietzsche and Zen : Self-overcoming without a Self by André van der Braak.

"Get beyond ‘myself’ and ‘yourself’! Experience cosmically!"
Beyond people. Considering matters, situations, for the facts of the matter only, not skewed by partiality.
Nietzsche sees things in terms of general value, not personal advantage, e.g. The Will to Power § 715

The standpoint of "value" is the same as that of the conditions of
preservation and enhancement, in regard to complex creatures of relative stability appearing in the course of evolution.
There are no such things as lasting and ultimate entities, no atoms,
no monads: here also "permanence" was first introduced by ourselves
(from practical, utilitarian, and other motives).

But nevertheless Nietzsche seeks to establish value perspectively, not unilaterally as per Plato, leaving it up for debate presumably, ibid. § 972

Plato, for instance, when he persuaded himself that "the good," as he
wanted it, was not Plato's good, but "the good in itself," the eternal
treasure which a certain man of the name of Plato had chanced to find
on his way!


But why is he using such Buddhism related terminology? Does he really not believe in individualism even though his entire philosophy seems to be built  around it as well as selfishness or egoism which he has not been against in any of his major books, but in this text he seems to averse to these concepts, why?

Nietzsche does think a thinking person should determine values by analysis and thoughtfulness but that doesn't necessarily mean the resulting values are egocentric or selfish. You might find interesting Nietzsche's ideas on justice (filtered through Heidegger) – "the function of a power that sees far and wide ... more than this or that person" yet established by the ruler who "measures things in accordance with his own measure." These are the kinds of issues of self-determination Nietzsche seems to be concerned with.


Hauptgedanke! Nicht die Natur täuscht uns, die Individuen und fördert ihre Zwecke durch unsre Hintergehung: sondern die Individuen legen sich alles Dasein nach individuellen d.h. falschen Maaßen zurecht; wir wollen damit Recht haben und folglich muß „die Natur“ als Betrügerin erscheinen. In Wahrheit giebt es keine individuellen Wahrheiten, sondern lauter individuelle Irrthümer — das Individuum selber ist ein Irrthum. Alles was in uns vorgeht, ist an sich etwas Anderes, was wir nicht wissen: wir legen die Absicht und die Hintergehung und die Moral erst in die Natur hinein. — Ich unterscheide aber: die eingebildeten Individuen und die wahren „Lebens-systeme“, deren jeder von uns eins ist — man wirft beides in eins, während „das Individuum“ nur eine Summe von bewußten Empfindungen und Urtheilen und Irrthümern ist, ein Glaube, ein Stückchen vom wahren Lebenssystem oder viele Stückchen zusammengedacht und zusammengefabelt, eine „Einheit“, die nicht Stand hält. Wir sind Knospen an Einem Baume — was wissen wir von dem, was im Interesse des Baumes aus uns werden kann! Aber wir haben ein Bewußtsein, als ob wir Alles sein wollten und sollten, ein Phantasterei von „Ich“ und allem „Nicht-Ich“. Aufhören, sich als solches phantastisches ego zu fühlen! Schrittweise lernen, das vermeintliche Individuum abzuwerfen! Die Irrthümer des ego entdecken! Den Egoismus als Irrthum einsehen! Als Gegensatz ja nicht Altruismus zu verstehen! Das wäre die Liebe zu den anderen vermeintlichen Individuen! Nein! Über „mich“ und „dich“ hinaus! Kosmisch empfinden!

http://www.nietzschesource.org/#eKGWB/NF-1881,11[7]

Hauptgedanke! Nicht die Natur täuscht uns, die Individuen und fördert ihre Zwecke durch unsre Hintergehung:

He refutes the idea that nature is it's own entity that seeks to deceive us for her own benefit.

sondern die Individuen legen sich alles Dasein nach individuellen d.h. falschen Maaßen zurecht;

Instead the failure of the individual is based on their own wrong assumptions about the world. Literally he accuses people of trying to measure with individualized rulers or standards.

wir wollen damit Recht haben und folglich muß „die Natur“ als Betrügerin erscheinen.

We want our intuitions of the world to be correct, so if they aren't we blame nature for deceiving us.

In Wahrheit giebt es keine individuellen Wahrheiten, sondern lauter individuelle Irrthümer — das Individuum selber ist ein Irrthum.

There are no individual truths, just individual error. So in other words he apparently reject the idea that you can make models by the individual that express the real world, you can only be wrong doing so. And after the "-" the (idea of the) individual itself is such an error.

Alles was in uns vorgeht, ist an sich etwas Anderes, was wir nicht wissen

Everything that happens inside of us is something different that we don't know about. Well yeah we know pretty little of what is going on inside of us and likely even less when Nietzsche was around.

wir legen die Absicht und die Hintergehung und die Moral erst in die Natur hinein.

We attribute intention, deception and morality to nature. So essentially we create the "individual", this purpose and moral driven entity, where there's just a mysterious fleshy robot that is doing stuff.

Ich unterscheide aber: die eingebildeten Individuen und die wahren „Lebens-systeme“, deren jeder von uns eins ist  — man wirft beides in eins,

I however differentiate between the "made up individual" and the "system of life" that everyone one of us actually is - one often conflates the two.

während „das Individuum“ nur eine Summe von bewußten Empfindungen und Urtheilen und Irrthümern ist, ein Glaube, ein Stückchen vom wahren Lebenssystem oder viele Stückchen zusammengedacht und zusammengefabelt, eine „Einheit“, die nicht Stand hält

While "the individual" is just the sum of all conscious experiences, judgements and errors, an imagination, a piece of the actual "system of life/life system" or rather loads of pieces glued together by thought and narratives, a unity that doesn't hold.

Wir sind Knospen an Einem Baume — was wissen wir von dem, was im Interesse des Baumes aus uns werden kann!

We (likely the idea of the individual) are but buds on a tree, what do we know of the tree and of what the tree wants us to become.

Aber wir haben ein Bewußtsein, als ob wir Alles sein wollten und sollten, ein Phantasterei von „Ich“ und allem „Nicht-Ich“.

But we have this idea as if we (the perception of being an individual) could and should be the entire thing, an illusion of an I (a self) and a non-I (everything else). So essentially the mind, the consciousness, the individual or however you'd want to call the thing that experiences, perceives itself as the whole human being and distinguishes itself from everything that is not under it's control, while in reality it's just a surface layer on top of a larger system that it claims, but not practically is.

Aufhören, sich als solches phantastisches ego zu fühlen! Schrittweise lernen, das vermeintliche Individuum abzuwerfen!

So he urges to rid oneself of this idea of the all encompasing ego and to rid oneself of the the idea of the concept of the individual.

Die Irrthümer des ego entdecken! Den Egoismus als Irrthum einsehen!

(by) realizing the errors of the ego and in consequence realize egoism itself as the error.

Als Gegensatz ja nicht Altruismus zu verstehen! Das wäre die Liebe zu den anderen vermeintlichen Individuen!

Where he feels the urge to explain that by the opposite of egoism he doesn't mean altruism, as that would just be the love of other individuals, but as stated previously he doesn't like the idea of individuals to begin with.

Nein! Über „mich“ und „dich“ hinaus! Kosmisch empfinden!

So the point isn't to give up the individual in favor of other individuals but rather to grow beyond the constraints of the individual, to experience cosmically.
So my interpretation of that would be, if that wasn't projected by the translation already, that he thinks of the idea of the individual, that encapsulates the self, ego, I, this perception of oneself as a unity and thus divides me and everything else, as ... well as a constraint. And so he argues that one should go beyond egoism, beyond this idea of encapsulation and to further extend ones perceptions and feelings and grow beyond the individual and to get closer to the life system itself that is to him apparently more than just our imaginations and models that the self makes up to control it.
So less rationality and more empiricism (including emotional empiricism)?

That link doesn't work.

@CriglCragl It should work "better" now. Though it's still not ideal... http://www.nietzschesource.org/#eKGWB and then then second to last tab on the left search for NF-1881 or Nachgelassene Fragmente/Posthumous Fragments year 1881 and there Group 11 section 7 is the relevant bit that is copied directly above. I  mean Nietzsche is in the Public Domain by now so if someone has a better source feel free to edit.

See Nietzsche and the Limits of Subjectivity:
The Theory of the Drives Daniel W. Smith Purdue University https://philarchive.org/archive/SMINAT-11. This reference has notations to Nietzsche's publications.  If the quotes are accurate then Nietzsche argues that the unconscious body reduces to biological drives. The drives exist in conflict with each other. The ego or conscious self is generated as consciousness of one or more of the unconscious drives. The source says Nietzsche goes one step farther. He argues that the body could theoretically interact with the surroundings based on the unconscious drives and so consciousness would not be necessary. In modern philosophy that idea is called a P-zombie or philosophical zombie. Philosophers who deny the existence of the self, or consider it an illusion, seem to rely on this argument for the possibility of philosophical zombies. But I see the conscious self as a natural product of an unconscious process, which persists for the time-being, so it is as real as any other natural event. I don't find arguments concerning p-zombies to be compelling, but I find strong biological drives that become conscious to be a fact of my body-mind experience.
The body has attributes of not-I or not-self when it is decomposed into constituent parts. This idea exists in Buddhism. But it seems that Nietzsche could have discovered or confirmed the concept using his own introspective investigations of the attributes arising in his body-mind experience.
This talk compares Nietzsche's philosophy to the theory of aggregates in Buddhism:
https://youtu.be/CB3fyDUg6Mo?t=502
I am aware that Nietzsche argues for master morality and against slave morality. Perhaps that is evidence of his belief in egotism or the distinct self. But in terms of biological drives master morality would be one expression of social drives and slave morality, as described by Nietzsche, would be another social drive that seems to frustrate, thwart, or oppose master morality.

Individualism and ego are almost interchangeable in this excerpt. He says to "disregard the individual and discover the fallacies in ego."
I think he is not speaking of the true individual but the individual that you build yourself up to be. This version of the individual is inherently tied to the ego. Once you understand the fallacies of your ego, you can begin to shed the "individual" that you think you are and become who you truly are.
He often refers to Dionysus in his writings. There is freedom in letting go of the societal constraints that hold you and shape you into "the individual" you are. He is not negating that there is an individual, he is disrupting your idea of the individual you are.

Welcome! Make sure you review https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help when you get a chance. :D

This must predate Freud, so this use of ego and egoism like that seems immediately suspect. Nietzsche died before Freud began publishing.
There seems to be an irreconcilable clash between one of Nietzsche's central doctrines, the Will to Power, and 'We are buds on a single tree'. That the book is about Zen makes the Buddist tones sound suspect, Nietzsche wasn't a fan of Buddism or Stoicism, and generally spoke against mysticism. There's also every reason to be suspicious of ideas that are only in his  Nachlass, he threw ideas around often that he did not later weave into his work.
Okay here is the Google Translate version from the German text:

Main idea! It is not nature that deceives us, the individuals, and
promotes its purposes through our deception: rather, it is the
individuals who arrange everything in existence according to
individual, i.e. false, dimensions; We want to be right about it and
consequently “nature” has to appear as a deceiver. In truth there are
no individual truths, but only individual errors - the individual
himself is an error. Everything that happens in us is in itself
something else that we do not know: we first place the intention and
the deception and the morality in nature. - But I differentiate: the
imagined individuals and the true "life systems", of which each of us
is one - one throws both into one, while "the individual" is only a
sum of conscious feelings and judgments and errors, a belief, a piece
of the real life system or many pieces thought and fabricated
together, a “unity” that does not hold up. We are buds on a tree -
what do we know about what we can become in the interest of the tree!
But we have a consciousness as if we wanted and should be everything,
a fantasy of “I” and everything “not-I”. Stop feeling like such a
fantastic ego! Learn step by step to throw off the supposed
individual! Discover the errors of the ego! See egoism as a mistake!
Altruism should not be understood as a contradiction! That would be
love for other supposed individuals! No! Beyond “me” and “you”! Cosmic
feeling!

It seems then it's not a pure translation issue.

Was this excerpt written before or after his major works? (since he has many times stepped away from his previously held beliefs), also I too was a bit perplexed to see the terms of ego and egoism being used before Freud even invented them, how is that even possible?

@KashifKhan, Etymonline: "egoism (n.)
1785, in metaphysics, "the theory that a person has no proof that anything exists outside his own mind,"  Meaning "doing or seeking of that which affords pleasure or advances interest" is from 1800; opposed to altruism, but not necessarily "selfish." Meaning "self-centeredness" is from 1840. Between egoism and egotism, egoism is more correctly formed; there formerly was a useful distinction, with egotism tending to take the senses "self-centeredness" and "extensive use of 'I'" and leaving to egoism the theoretical sense in metaphysics and ethics."
